# Can we capture an event when user presses X on the browser window?

Tags: javascript, browser-close

is there a way differentiate between refresh and close in Javascript? i use window.onbeforeunload now which works great in IE. To void this being called anywhere but close, i set a flag on EVERY button ...this seems like a difficult, hacky solution, but after searching for hours on google, it was the best i could find.

Isn't there an onclose event for IE????? or onclick?

I only need to support IE, not FF, so please don't post anything FF related, I can't use it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no way to trap in JavaScript the click of the X (close) button in **any** browser. In my opinion this is due to security concern... JavaScript can't (an will never be able to) listen to OS messages like the close of the current window.

The only solution I know (which is what you seem to use) is:

```
<body onunload="alert('Fired');">
```

But as you find out if fires on close and on reload. Again this is normal behavior because, AFAIK, for the JS engine a reload is the same as a close then a reopen of the same page.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no there is no IE specific onclose event.